# Creating rules in DB2

Tags: sql, postgresql, db2

In postgres SQL you can create rules which will activate on insert.

So I could make a rule like this and it will activate every time the given conditions are met:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE person_insert_id_change AS
ON INSERT TO person 
WHERE id = 127777
DO INSTEAD 
INSERT INTO person VALUES (1577761, new.firstname, new.secondname, new.dob);
```

Is there anyway to achieve something similar in DB2??

Thanks very much!

Comment: Which DB2 version/platform are you inquiring about?

Comment: @mustaccio it says the version number is 9070700 when I do select * from SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular scenario a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger should do what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_insert_id_change 
BEFORE INSERT ON person 
REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN n.id = 127777
BEGIN ATOMIC
  SET n.id = 1577761;
END
```

P.S. Not tested, obviously

Comment: @Charles --  only on views.

Comment: @mustaccio, thanks for the correction.  I've only seen them used on views...and a quick check of the syntax dialog didn't show that restriction.